# List all namespaces in k8s in Go

Tags: go, kubernetes, namespaces, terratest

Can anyone tell me how to list all namespaces in k8s using Go? I have been referencing this link but couldn't find anything that can list all namespaces.

Link: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/k8s

I don't see any `ListNamespaces` functions for the k8s package in Go.

Answer (score 5):

Try [kubernetes/client-go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/tree/master/examples), you can do like `clientset.CoreV1().Namespaces("").List(context.TODO(), metav1.ListOptions{})`. Your `clientset` maybe instantiate within the cluster or outside.

Answer (score 4):

To list namespaces you can use something like this:

```
func ListNameSpaces(coreClient kubernetes.Interface) {

    nsList, err := coreClient.CoreV1().
        Namespaces().
        List(context.Background(), metav1.ListOptions{})
    //checkErr(err)
    fmt.Println(err)

    for _, n := range nsList.Items {
        fmt.Println(n.Name)
    }
}
```