# kubernetes empty namespaces with golang

Tags: go, kubernetes

how to get the list of  the empty namespaces in kubernetes through go?

I want to write a code in golng by which I can find empty namespaces in kubernetes

Comment: empty from pod?

Comment: pods and any other resources.

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you Refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72406262/l) which helps to List all namespaces in k8s using Go and Develop for empty namespaces.

Comment: I used following command to find and delete empty namespaces in bash

Comment: kubectl get ns --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.name"  | xargs -I{} kubectl  get all -n {} 2>&1 | grep "No" | cut -d " " -f 5 |  xargs -I{} kubectl delete namespace {}

Comment: I need to run this bash in go so I can handle it more easily

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Kubernetes golang client to connect to your namespace and get all resources you want e.g. Pods and Deployments. So you can check if there is any resources or not.
For example, this code checks if there is a Deployment or not:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    ctrl "sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    config := ctrl.GetConfigOrDie()
    clientset := kubernetes.NewForConfigOrDie(config)

    namespace := "namespace"
    list, err := clientset.AppsV1().Deployments(namespace).List(ctx, metav1.ListOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("Namespace has %d Deployments", len(list.Items))
}
```

You can check the count of other resources as well.

Comment: This code only list Deployment  in namespace == "namespace"

Comment: You can get the list of namespaces and create a loop of them and find empty namespaces @SaeedKazemi